# When to favor taking a Consumer<T> instead of just returning T?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream, consumer

I came across the code which returned a list of "parse results" where always single result had only the exception value or successfuly parsed `T` object.

```
class SingleResult<T> {
    Optional<T> parseResult;
    Optional<Exception> parseException;
}
```

I refactored that "two purpose" class into separate classes representing successful or unsuccessfull import result, which follows also the processor refactor from returning `SingleResult<T>` to publish to two `Consumer`s:

```
SingleResult<T> process(Input );
```

to:

```
void process(Input , Consumer<SuccessResult<T>> , Consumer<Exception> )
```

**Now I am wondering if there are some clean code rules/criteria when we should favor such `Consumer` over just returning the result?** Should we apply this approach even for single strict type returned alwyas when possible?

Are there any additional drawbacks to the fact that we are "exporting" partial result during the processing still in progress? (which in many cases can be benefit for stream/event like processing and easily debuggable stack trace)

Comment: The main result of the refactoring as presented was to rewrite it in "continuation passing style". Similar style guides apply.

Comment: Isn't [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) the appropriate forum for this question?

Comment: `process` might execute the consumer on a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single immediate result, you should just return it, like Java developers did the last two decades. Deviating from the established pattern should have a reason.

Reasons for using a `Consumer` are either, not having exactly one result value or not having an immediate result value.

E.g. with [`Optional.ifPresent(Consumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) or [`Spliterator.tryAdvance(Consumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#tryAdvance-java.util.function.Consumer-) you are dealing with the possibility of not having a result value and with [`Iterable.forEach(Consumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) or [`Stream.forEach(Consumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) you might process more than one value.

And with [`CompletableFuture.thenAccept(Consumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenAccept-java.util.function.Consumer-) and its *async* variants, you have the possibility that the value still is not available when the method returns, so the consumer might get invoked at a later time.

In your case, it may be reasonable to offer such a method as the result may not be present, but it might be better to offer a method like

```
void process(Input i, BiConsumer<? super SuccessResult<T>, ? super Exception> c)
```

Compare with [`CompletableFuture.whenComplete(BiConsumer<? super T,? super Throwable> action)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)

But there is no reason to lock your class on either pattern.
Note that, e.g. both, `Optional` and `CompletableFuture`, offer methods to query the result value ([`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) resp, [`join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join--)), together with methods to pre-check whether these methods may succeed ([`isPresent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--) resp. [`isDone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#isDone--)/ [`isCompletedExceptionally()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#isCompletedExceptionally--)) in addition to the consumer variants (and other chaining methods).

So using a consumer is another opportunity, not meant to supersede existing patterns.

Comment: I aggree on the first part of the response, but applying your proposed BiConsumer approach will actually make this problem step back to original "is this an success or error response?"... Probably in such apporach consumer's first thing to do will be checking if success or exception is null/empty to dispatch the handling. I consider 2-Consumers approach a lot better

Comment: There are cases where a simple `if(t != null)` check is simpler than spreading the logic over two functions. But, as said, the key point is you don’t need to decide for a single API…

Comment: I probably could not aggree. With this `if (t!= null)` you introduces complication to the class. Actually with such condition you immediately run into problems with naming the class (should be probably named SomethingOrSomething). It's very common mistake to think that introducing more classes is increasing complexity. With such approach JDK with its > 4k classes would be called "too complex to be usable". Smaller components that are very simple and cleary states what they are and what they do just by looking at their name is a lot simpler.

Comment: @PiotrMüller I said “*there are cases*”, which does not imply that this applies to all cases, it doesn’t even claim that these cases are the majority. If you have already understood that the number of classes doesn’t say anything about the complexity, why are you ignoring the statement “*the key point is you don’t need to decide for a single API*”. You can offer a method accepting a `BiConsumer` *and* a method accepting two `Consumer`s *and* methods returning `Optional`s *and* you may decide *not* to offer that `BiConsumer` method. You are focusing on an irrelevant detail of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is better in most cases because of KISS and YAGNI.
The second approach can be useful if you are dealing with a stateful resource (e.g. InputStream) and want to enforce resource-safety.

With the first approach an owner of the `Input` publishes `SingleResult` outside the `process` method and has no control over it. So in case of streaming parsing of a huge input it's very easy to run into memory problems.

With the second approach parsed data never escapes the `process` method and an owner of the resource has full control over the data. So it open and close the input and apply consumers safely.

Just continue with the simplest solution unless you want to leverage advantages of pure functional programming. But beware that it is often very awkward in Java.

Comment: I cannot agree about KISS and YAGNI. YAGNI - You actually need two things (success or error) so this is not a justification, everything that is implemented in "2 class"/"2 consumer" approach is actually used. KISS - having a class with 2 purposes, where only one is actually used for specific instance is not simple, it's actually problematic and need some instructions/explanation to be properly used, the contract can be easily broken. 2-class approach is definatelly more "keep it simple". 2-consumer approach is even more simpler as you do not introduce any new types